# ng test fails it runs firefox lib

Tags: angular, karma-runner

`ng test fails` It produces a such error log.
Why does it try firefox? Few tests ago it works well with Chrome. I can not define what I have done wrong.

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/selenium-webdriver/firefox/binary.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'child_process' in '/home/marting/github/martin-eden-sailor/mw/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/firefox'
resolve 'child_process' in '/home/marting/github/martin-eden-sailor/mw/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/firefox'
  Parsed request is a module
  using description file: /home/marting/github/martin-eden-sailor/mw/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/package.json (relative path: ./firefox)
    Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
    resolve as module
      looking for modules in /home/marting/github/martin-eden-sailor/mw/
        using description file: /home/marting/github/martin-eden-sailor/mw/package.json (relative path: .)
          Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
          using description file: /home/marting/github/martin-eden-sailor/mw/package.json (relative path: ./child_process)
```

Comment: You mean it runs on chrome, not on firefox?

Comment: I mean that it is suggested to work in Chrome. But I see Firefox related   logs.

Comment: Inside karma.conf.js what is browsers config set for? If It is firefox change to chrome.